# Efficiently selecting the median and elements to its left and right

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-design

Suppose we have a set $S = \{ a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots , a_N \}$ of $N$ coders.

Each Coders has rating $R_i$ and the number of gold medals $E_i$, they had won so far.

A Software Company wants to hire exactly three  coders to develop an application.

For hiring three coders, they developed the following strategy:

1. They first arrange the coders in ascending order of ratings and descending order of gold medals.
2. From this arranged list, they select the three of the middle coders.
   E.g., if the arranged list is $(a_5,a_2,a_3,a_1,a_4)$ they select $(a_2,a_3,a_1)$ coders.

Now we have to help company by writing a program  for this task.

**Input:**

The first line contains $N$, i.e. the number of coders.

Then the second line contains the ratings $R_i$ of $i$th coder.

The third line contains the number of gold medals bagged by the $i$th coder.

**Output:**

Display only one line that contains the sum of gold medals earned by the three coders the company will select.

Comment: So higher-rated coders always win fewer medals??  If not, what order are you actually using to sort?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem of selecting the $k$th smallest element from the list solved by a class of algorithms called the [Selection Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm). There exist deterministic linear time selection algorithms so your problem can be solved in linear time by selecting the $n/2,n/2-1,n/2+1$th smallest elements from the original unsorted list.

Comment: If you'd like, you can run the selection algorithm once to find the median, and then find the minimum and maximum in the right and and left partitions respectively in one swoop.

Comment: @Sid @ Zach Langley  Hi can you please provide the Pseudo Code .i Went through wiki paedia but feels a bit tough to understand.So can you please provide the PseudoCode Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jack are you familiar with how quicksort works?  The randomized selection algorithm is essentially the same, except it only recurses on one side of each pivot.

Comment: @Jack: The wikipedia article on selection algorithms (linked in Sid's answer) contains pseudocode.  Google also works.

Comment: @Sid :: I read the wiki algorithm (Partition-based general selection algorithm) .Do we have to call select function three times  with k=n/2 ,k=n/2-1,k/2.Also what will be the value of left,right while calling function select.Also in partition function,what will be the val of partition Index.

Comment: @Jack: See Zach's comment. You can just call the function with k=n/2. Then partition the array into - one part being the set of elements <= the n/2th element and the other part having all elements greater. Then just do a linear scan to find the max and min elements of the two partitions resp.

Comment: @Sid and Zach: It's actually sufficient to keep track of the last two intervals used to recurse down to the $n/2$nd element and find the min/max therein.

Comment: @Pedro: if you're for instance using the median of medians algorithm, then you won't be able to do that.

Comment: @Sid: True, but in practice, the median of median algorithm is, to quote Wikipedia, "typically outperformed in practice by the expected linear algorithm with random pivot choices". It's also far more complicated to implement, which is why I wouldn't recommend using it unless you really have to ;)